# How to call a function from result set in MySQL Workbench?

Tags: mysql-workbench

I want to insert a row in a table from the result set view.

I have to call the function "now" in one of the columns.

How can I tell mysql workbench to not insert the value "now()" but its result ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay I've finally found the manual page mentioning that feature:

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/workbench/en/wb-sql-editor-query-panel.html

> It is possible to enter a function, or other expression, into a field.
>   Use the prefix \func to prevent MySQL Workbench from escaping
>   quotation marks. For example, for the expression md5('fred'), MySQL
>   Workbench normally would generate the code md5(\'fred\'). To prevent
>   this, enter the expression as \func md5('fred') to ensure that the
>   quoting is not escaped.